# I'm looking for a remote / networked kind of Terminal or something like this

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, fedora, terminal, qemu

let's think about this scenario:

Linux as host OS (I prefer Debian) and two different guest OSes, virtualized with qemu and kvm. The first one could be Fedora, the second one Arch.

The virtualized OSes should be in "headless" mode: I mean, I don't want to access these OS using a remote graphical desktop sharing application,so there should be no VGA output. Even more,I want to add the `-nographic` option to qemu.

At this point, what I really want to know is if you know if a specific tool exists or not. I'm thinking to a remote/networked terminal created with some kind of client/server model.

In short terms, I would like to install the server part ot the terminal on the virtualized os and the client part on the host OS and I will have, inside of it, all the commands that are available on the specific OS that I have virtualized.

For example,if I want to virtualize Fedora, I want to open this terminal on Ubuntu (that's the host OS) and inside of that terminal I want to configure every aspect I want of Fedora, including installing and launching applications.

So,if I want to run obs from Fedora while I'm using Ubuntu, I will install obs on Fedora and then I will issue the command "obs-studio" within the Fedora terminal and boom: obs-studio will start,but it hasn't been installed on Ubuntu, but on Fedora.

Someone knows if such kind of tool,exists ?

And no, an SSH client can't do what I want. Let me know,thanks.

Comment: What, exactly, makes you think that ssh can't do what you want?   ssh sounds like exactly what you need to use.    BTW, if  obs-studio is a GUI program then you'll need to have X and all the GUI libraries it needs installed on the VM.  You'll also need to use ssh's `-X` option on the client to request X forwarding and `X11Forwarding yes` in sshd_config on the VM.

Comment: no,i don't want SSH. I want a pure terminal application. No graphical applications can start from an ssh client. And Im not sure that an SSH client offers the equivalent commands of a terminal.

Comment: @roaima nope. i used more than enough of my time editing the unreadable wall of text into something vaguely readable.

Comment: @Marietto ssh **can** run graphical applications.  I told you how in my comment.

Comment: I don't want to use ssh. The virtual machines are running on the same host os. I prefer to have a greater feeling of integration between the running operating systems. And,graphically,a terminal / knsole offer a better sensation of using one only OS than an ssh client.

Comment: The graphics are carried across ssh. You don't see OBS sitting in a 24x80 window, if that's what you're worried about

Comment: "_No graphical applications can start from an ssh client_" - This works just fine here